# Прибавить значение к переменной при нажатии на кнопку vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[image]

Есть 4 кнопки с месяцами. Нужно чтобы при нажатии на 2 мес. к процентами прибавлялось 2,5  , на 4 - 7,5 , на 8 - 10 и тд.
Число процентов это переменная, при клике на кнопки я могу сделать так чтобы переменная увеличивалась, но проблема в том, что не получается сделать сбрасывание предыдущего нажатия и значения, когда нажата другая кнопка из этих четырех.
Кнопки:

```
    <div class="buttons">
                <span :class="{active : two_m}" @click="two_m = !two_m ; month()">2 мес.</span>
                <span>4 мес.</span>
                <span>8 мес.</span>
                <span>12 мес.</span>
     </div>
<p>{{percent}}</p>
```

Метод:

```
 month() {
            if (this.two_m ) {
                this.percent += 2.5;

            }
        },
```

Данные в data

```
two_m:false, //говорит о том, что кнопка не нажата
percent: 0, // сами проценты
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    months: 2,
    percent: 2.5
  },
  methods: {
    setM: function(m, p) {
      this.months = m;
      this.percent = p;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div class="buttons">
    <span :class="{active : months == 2}" @click="setM(2,2.5)">2 мес.</span>
    <span :class="{active : months == 4}" @click="setM(4,7.5)">4 мес.</span>
    <span :class="{active : months == 8}" @click="setM(8,10)">8 мес.</span>
</div>
<p>{{percent}}% к вашему депозиту</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    default: 5,
    percent: 7, // 5+2 (percent+default)
  },
  methods: {
    add(p){
      this.percent = this.default;
      this.percent += p;
    },
  },
})
```

```css
span{
  padding: 5px;
  cursor:pointer;
  user-select:none;
}
span:hover{
  background:grey;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
    <div
    >
      <span
        @click="add(2)"
      >
        2
      </span>
      <span
        @click="add(3)"
      >
        3
      </span>
      <span
        @click="add(4)"
      >
        4
      </span>
    </div>
    <p>Результат: {{percent}}%</p>
  </template>
</div>
```